# Is it possible to open a shapefile using a ArcGIS Runtime for Windows Mobile application

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-mobile

I need to build a tablet application using ArcGIS Runtime for Windows Mobile. Is there a way to open a shapefile (or a pgdb) without having to convert it to a .db file first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Windows Mobile](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgismobile/key-features) only works with .db files. The only way I succeeded in using shapefile data was to export an empty .db file with Arc Catalog, then, in my application, programatically transfer the shapefile data into the .db file. The major downside was that all the elements transfered appeared as "added features"